# Cannot GET from correct location with axios in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

The issue I am having seems to be that axios is ignoring my GET path when published to build, but works as expected in dev mode.
I am using the following to retrieve local .html files and parse them into my vue component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-html="message"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      message: '',
    }
  },
  async mounted(){
    const mypath = 'http://***.com/posts/' + this.$route.params.post + '.html';
    const ip = await this.$axios.$get(mypath);
    this.message = ip;
  }
}
</script>
```

This .vue is located at "pages/blogs/posts/_post.vue"
My .html files are located in "static/posts/examplepost.html"

When running in dev mode, if I change the first part of the path to either "http://localhost:3000/posts/" or just "/posts/", everything works perfect.
However, when I publish to the web and link to a blog post url, I get a 404 at the following path: `"https://***.com/blogs/posts/examplepost.html"`
Why is this working in dev mode but not when built?

I have tried moving the posts into the "/blogs/posts/" location and have tried creating a new instance of axios and setting the baseURL directly in my component and get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
The issue was that I was using `<a>` in order to create my links to the individual pages created by the "_post.vue"

```
<a :href="'posts/' + blog.link">
```

Using `<nuxt-link>`, like it is recommended everywhere, fixed the issue:

```
<nuxt-link :to="'posts/' + blog.link">
```